# Angularjs ng-click function executing on second click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am learning AngularJS, Currently I am doing one exercise, which is having angularjs ng-click function, I am getting the result on second click of my upload button using ng-click(As I am displaying my json content after clicking on 'upload' button), I don't know where I am doing wrong ? Please let me know.

Comment: I have created fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/u3zgrgcx/1/

Comment: can you show us what code you have?

Comment: I forgot to include fiddle in my question, I have created at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/u3zgrgcx/1/ .

Comment: works fine as i can see on first click only. can't replicate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
$scope.dataItems.push(data.value);    
console.log("Data VALUES: "+data.value);
});

$scope.$apply();
```

The file reader API will work asynchronously, outside of the angularjs "flow". Therefore, you have to make apply int he end of the onload function, like in the above sample.

**OLD:**

Are you using the angularjs $http service? Otherwise, when you get the data back, are you doing a scope.$apply to refresh with the new data?

Comment: what? is this answer or you are commenting?

Comment: Created fiddle at: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/u3zgrgcx/1/ . As I am not using $http.

Comment: It's an answer, with whatever best answer I could give with came into my mind. The problem is that I don't have enough points to add comments, so I have to answer, and since I have to answer I have to suggest what I can think of that could be the problem. :/

Comment: @Dhana please check my answer again.

Comment: @rvalerio, Yes, your solution has worked fine. Thanks  for your help !!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `$scope.$apply();` at the end of loadFile method.
Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u3zgrgcx/2/).

Tell me if works fine.